# Jquery Dialog close unexpectedly using ASP Master Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, dialog

When i press the "Specify Services" button the dialog appears but it seems that is doing a postback and the the dialog is closing unexpectedly

```
<asp:Content ID="Content0" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPLaceHolderHeader" runat="server">
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $( function() {
            var dialog;   


        dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 400,
          width: 350,
          modal: false,
          buttons: {        

          }
        });    


        $( "#spc" ).button().on( "click", function() {
          dialog.dialog( "open" );

        });
          } );
          </script>      

     </asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <button id="spc">Specify Services</button>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

              <form>
                <fieldset>
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" >
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" >         

                  <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>

</asp:Content>
```

I have tried not using the Master Page/Content and that works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the button tag acts as a submit button. So if you do not want it to do a postback you need to specify the button type.

`<button id="spc" type="button">Specify Services</button>`

[Button types](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)